# Why doesn't SAS/ACCESS work ?

Tags: sas, teradata

`proc setinit` shows `SAS/ACCESS`

```
 proc setinit;
 run ;

  . . . 
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files                                         
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC
```

---

Now that I run `libname` I get

```
LIBNAME testlib teradata user=xxx password=XXXXXXXX;
ERROR: The TERADATA engine cannot be found.

LIBNAME testlib sasiotra user=xx password=XXXXXXXX;
ERROR: The TERADATA engine cannot be found.
```

**Why ? How to fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you do not have a license for SAS/ACCESS to Teradata.  You do have ACCESS for ODBC.  Create an ODBC connection to Teradata and use that connection in SAS.